# Test startegy for liquibase changes

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, testing, liquibase

I am part of a team that works on a SpringBoot application and we use liquibase for maintaining our database changes.

Config data that has to be added/removed/modified goes as part of a change-set.

The problem is that there are no ways of validating any liquibase changes from our end. There has been a couple of occurrences lately where an incorrect config data modification change-set broke a functionality.

Is there a way I can implement a test-case sort of thing for the liquibase change-sets to prevent such things from happening in future. If yes, could you please point me to the right direction as I am completely clueless about how to implement that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase recently introduce a new capability that can help: [quality checks](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/quality-checks.html)

The capability lets you scan your changelogs and changesets for patterns that are of concern to you.  For example it can detect when privileges are being granted or a sql statement or changeset contains a `DROP TABLE...` statement. If you know the patterns that cause problems then this capability might be of help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pete. I'll look into the documentation and see if it fits our purpose.

Comment: unfortunately this does not meet my requirement. It only enforces best practice behaviors while adding liquibase change set.